# Find out which parser BeautifulSoup4 is using?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I've written a script using beautifulsoup4 that works in one machine but not another. The reason is that on that other machine, BeautifulSoup() constructor auto-convert `<br>` to `<br/>` whereas it's not the behaviour on my machine. Believe it or not, it matters to my script.

I figured that the two machines might be using 2 different underlying HTML parsers. How can I find out what parsers they are using? I understand that I can specify a parser library to be used by BeautifulSoup, but first I need to know what library to unify to.

Both machines run python2.7.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is documented, but if you look at [the source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/__init__.py#L82), the instance of the class selected according to your `builder` and/or `features` arguments gets stored in the `builder` attribute.

So, you probably want `type(soup.builder).__name__`, which will give you one of:

- `HTMLParserTreeBuilder`: use `html.parser`
- `LXMLTreeBuilder`: use `lxml`
- `LXMLTreeBuilderForXML`: use `xml`
- `HTML5TreeBuilder`: use `html5lib`

(Of course this assumes you haven't written your own custom builder around some other parser, but if you'd done that, hopefully you'd know it.:)